# How to RawPrint a PDF417 using QzTray?

Tags: javascript, epson, qz-tray

I have a Qz Tray instance that can print text, but I'm somewhat lost as to how to generate the pdf417 barcode from a string.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FInally i generated the PDF417 as an image and then printed it by Using Raw Image Printing offered by QzTray.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using a raster graphic some languages, such as ZPL have support for PDF417.  Here are examples [directly from the Zebra site](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/pdf417_barcode.htm):

> PDF417 ZPL example commonly used for automotive applications
>
> ```
> ^XA
> ^FO50,50^BY3,3^B7N,8,5,7,21,N^FH_^FD[)>_1E06_1DP12345678_1DQ160_1D1JUN123456789A2B4C6D8E
> _1D20LA6-987_1D21L54321 ZES_1D15KG1155_1DBSC151208_1D7Q10GT_1E_04^FS
> ^XZ
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> Basic example ZPL format with PDF417 using ^B7
>
> ```
> ^XA^BY2,3 
> ^FO50,50^B7N,5,5,,83,N 
> ^FDZebra Technologies strives to be the expert supplier of innovative solutions to specialty demand labeling and ticketing problems of business and government. We will attract and retain the best people who will understand our customer's needs and provide them with systems, hardware, software, consumables and service offering the best value, high quality, and reliable performance, all delivered in a timely manner.^FS 
> ^XZ
> ```
>
> [image]

Adapting this to QZ Tray is pretty simple...

```
var config = qz.configs.create("ZDesigner");
var data = [
   "^XA^BY2,3\n", 
   "^FO50,50^B7N,5,5,,83,N\n",
   "^FDZebra Technologies strives to be the expert supplier of innovative solutions to specialty demand labeling and ticketing problems of business and government. We will attract and retain the best people who will understand our customer's needs and provide them with systems, hardware, software, consumables and service offering the best value, high quality, and reliable performance, all delivered in a timely manner.^FS\n",
   "^XZ"
];
qz.print(config, data);
```